# delete column in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using this VBScript to delete column A in Excel:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wy = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\XX\Historical_data_extract.xlsx")

objExcel.Visible = True
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Delete
objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook..Close
```

The script is just opening the file but not deleting anything
Why is it so?

Also how can I delete multiple column A and J?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to

```
Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wy = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\XX\Historical_data_extract.xlsx")    
objexcel.Visible = True
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
wy.Save
wy.Close
```

Your code were attempting to delete a range in an other workbook than the workbook that you had opened.

Columns E and G can be deleted by

```
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Delete
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").EntireColumn.Delete 
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: How can i delete multiple column example E and G also @Søren Holten Hansen

Comment: @nnnnmmm You would do that like: `wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:G").EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: That would delete the columns E through G, not just the columns E and G.

Comment: Beware that deleting a column shifts the higher columns, so column G becomes column F after you delete column E.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is deleted because the workbook is opened into a variable `wy`, but you try to delete the column from a workbook in the variable `objWorkbook`. Which you didn't initialize.

You delete another column by specifying another column instead of `A:A`. Beware that deleting a column decrements the index of all columns right of the deleted column (`B` becomes `A`, `C` becomes `B`, and so on), so I'd suggest to delete them in reverse order.

```
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J:J").Delete
wy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Delete
```

Comment: How can i delete multiple column example E and G also